# Why does it go to exception when parse to integer?

Tags: java, android

I can´t figure out why this Integer.parseInt makes an exception, its a NullpointerException..

```
try
{
    int numberOfPictures = Integer.parseInt(editTextNumberOfGames
                        .getText().toString()); 
    Toast toast =Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "ratt", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT); 
                toast.show();
} catch (Exception e)
{
    Toast toast =Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "fel", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT); 
                toast.show();
}
```

Comment: is editTextNumberOfGames initialized?

Comment: Check what editTextNumberOfGames
                        .getText().toString() returns

Comment: What is your stack trace ? is it NULL POinter exception or NUmberFormatException ?

Comment: Stop swallowing the exception and do `e.printStackTrace()` in your `catch {}` block, then go over those logs or provide them for us.

Comment: @ratchetfreak: well i had not found it with findViewById.... thanks

Answer (score -2, accepted):

It throws an expecption because `editTextNumberOfGames` is null

initialize editTextNumberOfGames correctly, or if for whatever reason you cannot garuantee, that it is initialized then

```
int numberOfPictures;
if (editTextNumberOfGames != null) {
   numberOfPictures = Integer.parseInt(editTextNumberOfGames.getText());
}
```

Comment: `getText()` will never return `null`.

Comment: His object is called `editTextNumberOfGames`, and we're working with Android. Do you *really* think it's not an `EditText`?

Comment: My answer is totally correct, he did not initialize his editTextNumberOfGames properly.

Answer (score 2):

Have you used a debugger to verify that editTextNumberOfGames is not null when you get to this code?

You can temporary break up the Integer.parseInt(editTextNumberOfGames.getText().toString()) statement to see exactly which part of the compound statement is causing the exception.

See http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Integer.html

Answer (score 0):

As  ratchet freak pointed out in comments, i had not done this:

editTextNumberOfGames = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextNrOfPictures);

Thanks for all help though.

Comment: As i wrote you "Or better initialize editTextNumberOfGames correctly." See my answer